# Angularjs application security concerns

Tags: angularjs

I have to create a angularjs application which is mainly handled real time transaction from diffrent vendors.Actually our Payment transaction application is already made in asp.net and running and now for keeping fast performance in the mind we are converting this application in angularjs with web api support.
My main concern is the security of the application as it is mainly dealing with transactions.
In our old application all the things is handled throung session but as we know in web api session is not supported by default.By we have made it through custom class.
Please guide me here ..Is the desicion is right or I get problem in futures.
How can i handled all the incoming url refrenses and session values..?

Comment: Please also let me know that if i make session avaiable to web api by custom class caused any future issue or not?

Comment: The concerns are not angular specific. Client-side javascript apps expose security internals to the user's browser. You must take care to not expose more than you mean to. Typically you will be returning some kind of session identifier that is then stored in localStorage/sessionStorage or a cookie.

Comment: How can I redirect a old url like www.abc.com/test.aspx to currect angular page which is at the directory ~/app/views/test.html.

Comment: Thanks aet for you reply.